# On $\sigma(n)<n+\frac{n}{2}\log\frac{n+1}{n-1}+\frac{n}{4} \left(\sum_{\substack{d|n,1<d<n}}\log\frac{(n+d)(n+1)}{(n-d)(n-1)}\right)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, asymptotics, arithmetic-functions, experimental-mathematics

I've derived for $n>1$ and $\sigma(n)$ the sum of divisor function $\sum_{d|n}d$ the following inequality 
$$\sigma(n)<n+\frac{n}{2}\log\frac{n+1}{n-1}+\frac{n}{4} \left(\sum_{\substack{d|n,1<d<n}}\log\frac{(n+d)(n+1)}{(n-d)(n-1)}\right).$$

For the proof, if it isn't wrong, I've used an inequality derived in [1]. Currently I don't made computations with my computer, and I want to know it previous inequality is good in the sense that $RHS/\sigma(n)$ is relatively small.

> **Question.** Can you tell me, in words if the inequality it seems sharper or not, the computational behaviour (with a summary table or a graphic using a computer) of $RHS/\sigma(n)$ for $1<n\leq N$ and $N$ sufficiently large. Of course you can provide us a summary of your results. If you find a counterexample please tell me to discard this inequality. Optionally if you know how estimate this ratio, from a theoretical viewpoint, please tell me. Thanks in advance.

**References:**

Klambauer, On a Property of $x^ne^{-x}$, The American Mathematical MONTHLY **1988**, page 551.

Comment: Please ( for any user) feel free to modify previous question or post if it if this is an improvement, I am not a professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly speaking, your result is that
$$ \sigma(n) \ll n \log n,$$
where I use $\ll$ as a sort of [big Oh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) notation. It's actually known that
$$ \sigma(n) \ll n \log \log n.$$
The difference between what you've shown and what is known is the difference between $\log n$ and $\log \log n$. In short, the second is much, much smaller. For instance, $\log 10^6 \approx 13.81$ and $\log \log 10^6 \approx 2.62.$ And this difference becomes more pronounced as $n$ gets large, even though it happens slowly.

As $n$ gets large, the ratio between your error and the known error is unboundedly large. But to be fair, the rate of divergence is quite slow.

Comment: Very thanks much,  I take my notes and close the question @mixedmath

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear to me exactly what you are asking the community to provide, but you can compare this to previously established bounds to get a sense for how well you are doing. In particular, a mathematician named Robin showed that
$$
\sigma(n) < e^{\gamma}n\log(\log(n)) + \frac{.65n}{\log(\log(n))}
$$
holds for all $n\geq 3$. The constant $.65$ isn't quite right, but I don't have my references handy (maybe someone can comment/edit one in), but already this beats your bound for large $n$. So you do not have a "sharp" inequality, but it may have merits in that the proof might be easier than Robin's result. You will probably have to do the computational aspects of your problem yourself. I recommend using Python or Sage.

Comment: Very thanks much @Tenno, precisely I require as question that the community provide to me the computations. I know Robin's result, but I don't know how compare previous result with mine, and claim that mine isn't sharp without computations. Perhaps you have compared magnitude order or functions. Too it is asked in my question. Possibly that my inequality isn't sharper since to obtain this I don't use special methods. Very thanks much for yours notes, in true. Currently I don't can made  good computations with my computer,  but I am learn Free Pascal.

Comment: I think this inequality depends on the Riemann Hypothesis being true? Maybe I'm wrong.